# Like and Dislike system by JQuery, sql and php

Tags: php, jquery, sql

I have a post and like and dislike.
Now, issue is this if I am hitting like button so, the number of like's is increasing again and again.
**So, I only want to know how I do like and dislike once per user.**

Here is the JQuery Code :-

```
$(document).on("click", "#usrcmmntyes", function (e) {
    var yes = $(this).attr("onclick"); 
    //console.log(yes);
    });
function like_update(id){
        jQuery.ajax({
        url:'setrw3.php',
        type:'post',
        data:'type=like&pro_id='+id,
        success:function(result){
      var cur_count=jQuery('.like_loop_'+id).html();
      cur_count++;
      jQuery('.like_loop_'+id).html(cur_count);
    }
    });
}

$(document).on("click", "#usrcmmntno", function (e) {
    var no = $(this).attr("onclick"); 
    //console.log(no);
    });
function dislike_update(id){
    jQuery.ajax({
        url:'setrw3.php',
        type:'post',
        data:'type=dislike&pro_id='+id,
        success:function(result){
      var cur_count=jQuery('.dislike_loop_'+id).html();
      cur_count++
      jQuery('.dislike_loop_'+id).html(cur_count);
    }
    });
}
```

And, Here is the PHP code :-

```
$type=$_POST['type'];
$id=$_POST['pro_id'];

if($type=='like'){
    $sql="update problems set right_count=right_count+1 where pro_id=$id";
}else{
    $sql="";
}

if($type=='dislike'){
    $sql="update problems set wrong_count=wrong_count+1 where pro_id=$id";
}else{
    $sql="";
}

$res=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand that Stack Overflow is not meant for asking complete solutions. It is your job as programmer to create solutions. I am still going to be kind and help you to get started with this.

You should use sessions or JWT as solution to track user. When user performs action that user should only be able to do once you should keep log that action down. Store that information to database that user has liked or disliked content.

Here is example how you could do it. This is example of tables that you should have in your database

```
| User |     | Likes  |      | Content |
|------|     |--------|      |---------|
| uuid | <-- | uuid   | -->  | postid  |
| name |     | postid |      | content |
| email|     | action |      -----------
| etc..|     ----------
--------
```

Basically you have 3 different SQL tables. Important one in this case is table called "Likes". It tracks users actions on posts. Then backend checks if user has already made an action on that specific post.